# matching word in javascript up to a whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
var str = "Format-ABC-D Type-O"
```

I would like to get "ABC-D" out of this string. so fat I have

```
str.(/Format-(\w+)/i)[1]
```

But this just gives me "ABC". How can I match up to a whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match anything else than whitespaces, not just word characters:

```
/Format-(\S+)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the string up to the whitespace first, then do your thing. So

```
str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(" ")) // str is "Format-ABC-D"
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works, but I forgot to mention I could have a string like var str = "Item-X Format-ABC-D Type-O"